# Power object of terminal object is subobject-classifier?

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

Power object of terminal object in finitely complete category is claimed to be subobject-classifier in https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/power+object. The connection is otherwise quite evident, but how to show $\in_1$ is necessarily terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For each object $X$, use the power object condition of $\Omega^1$ for the identity subobject $1_X\colon X\longrightarrow X$.